# Multiple files upload in selenium webdiver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I want to upload 5 files,but my 'file input' is same name/id,how can i possible to upload five files.
My HTML code is:

```
<div>
    <table id="listtable">
    </table>
    <br/>
    <input type="hidden" name="delFiles" id="deletefiles"/> 
    <table id="filetable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="file" size="27px" id="page" name="page"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#">
                    <img name="del" onclick="removeRow(this);" title="delete" alt="delete" src="images/user_delete.png"/>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="file" size="27px" name="page"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img name="del" onclick="removeRow(this);" title="delete" alt="delete" src="images/user_delete.png"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="file" size="27px" name="page"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img name="del" onclick="removeRow(this);" title="delete" alt="delete" src="images/user_delete.png"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="file" size="27px" name="page"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img name="del" onclick="removeRow(this);" title="delete" alt="delete" src="images/user_delete.png"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="file" size="27px" name="page"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <img name="del" onclick="removeRow(this);" title="delete" alt="delete" src="images/user_delete.png"/>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <br/>
    <br/>
</div>
```

Comment: You really need to review all your asked questions and accept answers. If no answers are satisfied, please provide feedbacks to the repliers. http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: @Namitha, your HTML will not shown unless you indent it by a tab or four spaces. Do not rollback the edit I made, or simply do this yourself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [webdriver:upload multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23955430/webdriverupload-multiple-files)

Answer (score 15):

This works on Chrome:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("input1")).sendKeys("path/to/first/file-001 \n path/to/first/file-002 \n path/to/first/file-003");
```

Comment: works for me as well :) For everyone else who is encountering errors, just make sure that you're sending everything as a single string and not calling `sendKeys` more than once.

Comment: not work for me, what's your chrome version?

Answer (score 1):

You would do so the same as you would if you were only uploading one file.

```
driver.findElement(By.id("input1")).sendKeys("path/to/first/file");
driver.findElement(By.id("input2")).sendKeys("path/to/second/file");
driver.findElement(By.id("input3")).sendKeys("path/to/third/file");
driver.findElement(By.id("input4")).sendKeys("path/to/fourth/file");
driver.findElement(By.id("input5")).sendKeys("path/to/fifth/file");
driver.findElement(By.id("upload")).click();
```

Obviously, you'll need to put in your own correct IDs or whatever.

Comment: But here all textboxs name=page.So how can I give like this?

Comment: In that case I guess you'd need to make a list of the
`input` elements first.

`inputs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//input[@type='file']");`
`inputs[1].sendKeys("path/to/first/file");`
`inputs[2].sendKeys("path/to/second/file");`
`inputs[3].sendKeys("path/to/third/file");`
`inputs[4].sendKeys("path/to/fourth/file");`
`inputs[5].sendKeys("path/to/fifth/file");`

But it would be far better if you could iterate over the list whilst adding in a string that contains the paths from an array using the same index position.

Answer (score 0):

that easy
like 
`//input[@type="file"]`
will point to the first input tag
and 
`(//input[@type="file"])[{INDEX}]` 
where INDEX is the number of the of the input tag
note: indexing in xpath starts from 1

OR you can use the

```
file_tag_list =driver.find_elements_by_xpath(//input[@type="file"])
```

function that the python syntax you can find it for different languages just google it.
this function will return a list of webdriver element
and then you can

```
file_tag_list[0].send_keys(filepath)
file_tag_list[1].send_keys(filepath)
```

Answer (score -1):

Holy ##### it even works in PHP:

```
public function waitForAjax()
{
    while(true)
    {
        $ajaxIsComplete = array(
            'script' => 'return jQuery.active == 0',
            'args' => array()
        );
        $ajaxIsComplete = $this->execute($ajaxIsComplete);
        if ($ajaxIsComplete) {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you :)