# How do I upload multiple files with Protractor?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, selenium, selenium-webdriver, protractor

I am using `webdriver.WebElement.sendKeys` and Path to upload a single file. The code looks like this:

```
var path = require('path'),
  uploadInput = element(by.css("input[type=file]")),
  fileToUpload = "../test_image/download.jpeg",
  absolutePath = path.resolve(__dirname, fileToUpload);

  uploadInput.sendKeys(absolutePath);
```

That works fine, for one file. I need to test multiple file uploads. How do I pass multiple files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Selenium still does not support multiple file uploads:

- [`Support <input type=file multiple>`](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1275%20%20%20[1]:%20https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2239)

But, according to [webdriver:upload multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23955430/webdriverupload-multiple-files), you should be able to solve it **in Chrome** *by joining file paths with a new-line character*:

```
uploadInput.sendKeys(absolutePath1 + "\n" + absolutePath2);
```

Also see:

- [File Upload - Uploading multiple files in FireFox](https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/1275%20%20%20[1]:%20https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=2239)