# How to upload multiples files in filepicker using protractor? (Firefox browser)

Tags: firefox, selenium-webdriver, protractor, filepicker

I am uploading single file in filepicker but not able to upload multiple files.

Comment: Could you provide a link to the actual picker you are working with? Basically, make the problem reproducible for us. Thanks!

Comment: @alecxe I am able to upload single file but what i want to do is i have to upload multiple files present in the folder. How can i upload multiple files.

Comment: @alecxe I have a folder which contains 50 files and i want to upload all files..please help me

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I upload multiple files with Protractor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749468/how-do-i-upload-multiple-files-with-protractor)