# upload multiple files with protractor in firefox

Tags: typescript, webdriver, protractor

I read about upload multiple files in firefox but I couldn't find best solution.

It works fine for chrome:

```
uploadInput.sendKeys(absolutePath1 + "\n" + absolutePath2);
```

But how to do in firefox?

Comment: Related, yet not an answer since the FireFox link in the answer results in 404: [How do I upload multiple files with Protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31749468/how-do-i-upload-multiple-files-with-protractor/)

Comment: maybe you know an unofficial solution for multiple uploads?