# Choose a File from OpenFileDialog with C#

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, openfiledialog

I have a little problem - I don't know how to Select a File and Open it in the Mozilla OpenFileDialog.

First, I open the Dialog by pressing "Browse" with Selenium and then I want to put in a File-Name (I know the exact location via Environment variable)

In my case: Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Testplatz_Config_Location") + "\TestConfig.fpc"

So my Question, does anyone know how to handle an already open OpenFileDialog using C# - Or is it perhaps possible to handle this with Selenium?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sendKeys()` on the file upload element to upload a file using selenium by path. I would suggest using this instead of AutoIT or Robot.

So instead of clicking on the browse button, you send the path directly to the file input element using `sendKeys()`.

Example:

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("file_input"));
element.SendKeys(
    Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Testplatz_Config_Location") + "\TestConfig.fpc");
```

Comment: Already tried this but it doesn't add the whole Filepath - it only inserts the last part: TestConfig.fpc

which doesn't allow me to open the File as it is not in the starting directory of the OpenFileDialog

Comment: Then something must be wrong with your environment variable. What is the output when you print Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Testplatz_Config_Location") + "\TestConfig.fpc"?

Comment: The Environment Variable output works fine, as i am using it on a few different locations in the code. It just doesnt pass all of the text into this field

Comment: add: Ok i tried to take the Environment part out of the SendKeys and create a string upfront - now it works - Seems like the SendKeys somehow doesnt handle the Environment Variable right

Comment: Side-note: Uploading multiple files is also possible via SendKeys - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23955430/selenium-webdriver-upload-multiple-files

Answer (score 2):

Selenium does not provide any native way to handle windows based pop ups. But we have some third party tools like **AutoIT** and **RobotClass** to handle those windows based pop ups. Refer those and give it a a try. 
[AutoIT with Selenium and Java](http://toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/)

Comment: I dont really want to use an external tool. Right now i have something similiar with a MozillaDialogClass that asks for a Username and Password. There it works with FindWindow and a SendMessage Commando - but somehow it doesnt work for the OpenFileDialog so i can just send keystrokes to it.

Answer (score 1):

Selenium/SeleniumWebDriver does not provide any native way to handle windows based popups. Still, the best way is to miss this popup using

```
IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.Id("file_input"));
element.SendKeys(filePath);
```

but this is not allways is possible. And if it is not, you can use my lib:

https://github.com/ukushu/DialogCapabilities

by the following way:

OpenFileDialog:

```
// for English Windows
DialogsEn.OpenFileDialog(@"d:\test.txt");

//For windows with russian GUI
Dialogs.OpenFileDialog("Открыть", @"d:\test.txt");
```

MultiFile selection in OpenFileDialog:

```
var filePaths = new string[] {@"d:\test1.txt", @"d:\test2.txt", @"d:\test3.txt"};

//Or for Eng windows:
DialogsEn.OpenFileDialog(filePaths);

//for russian language OS
Dialogs.OpenFileDialog("Открыть", filePaths);
```

Answer (score 0):

i used selenium with Robot class from Java awt. This is my solution

```
public static void setClipboardData(String string) {
//StringSelection is a class that can be used for copy and paste operations.
        StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(string);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(stringSelection, null);
    }

    public static void uploadFile(String fileLocation) {
        try {
//Setting clipboard with file location
            setClipboardData(fileLocation);
//native key strokes for CTRL, V and ENTER keys
            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
            robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        } catch (Exception exp) {
            exp.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```