# How to choose a file in an already opened FileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, testing, selenium-webdriver, openfiledialog

I want to choose a file from an already opened `OpenFileDialog` which is shown by the browser.

I want to use code similar to the following example:

```
OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
dialog.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
dialog.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
```

The problem is, that I cant access `dialog`. I can't reference it.

**Edit:** 
I use the selenium-webdriver for automated testing. But the fileDialog is presented by the website I want to test.

Comment: When you say you can't access `dialog`, do you mean you don't have a reference to it, or something else?  *Can* you get a reference to it?

Comment: What do you mean by "I cant access dialog"? You need to show the dialog - see the  example here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: yes, I edited the text.

Comment: Can you show all of the relevant code.

Comment: So does the dialog not belong to your program (what is "the browser" in this context)? If it does, *where* is it in your code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [choose a File from OpenFileDialog with C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37524651/choose-a-file-from-openfiledialog-with-c-sharp)

Comment: That fact that this is a *browser owned* open file dialog changes things significantly.  Is it opened from javascript running in the page?

Comment: Selenium WebDriver cannot handle objects outside the web browser - in your case, the dialog. If your intention is to upload a file, @Anderson's link would help you.

Answer (score 0):

without an OpenFileDialog you say?
you have a few options for this..

one being a method i used here -
https://github.com/Ricky310711/RDExplorer

You would need to create a new panel with a ListView and populate it with local folders and files, add a double click event handler to select the item selected by storing it in a string.