# How do I upload multiple files through selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have 4 images in a folder and need to upload all of them together into my application. I have done single file upload through selenium using sendKeys, but the multi file upload is a challenge!

Comment: Can you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37941694/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-selenium

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to upload Multiple files in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37941694/how-to-upload-multiple-files-in-selenium)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [webdriver:upload multiple files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23955430/webdriverupload-multiple-files)

Answer (score 1):

```
WebElement uploadElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath("   "));
//Single file upload
uploadElement.sendKeys("C:\\foldername\\abcd.png");

//Multi file upload - simultaneous
uploadElement.sendKeys("C:/foldername/firstImg.png \n C:/foldername/secondImg.png \n C:/foldername/thirdImg.png");
```

**Note** : `\n` needs to be preceeded with space